# I can't get the output to show from an array PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, count, output

**NOTICE:** I know the scroll bar for my code looks insane, if you just scroll to the bottom, you will see where I am trying to output the code.

I am trying to output the results of a select query search. 
I have successfully retrieved the results which satisfy the WHERE conditions in a stand alone php file eg. not imbedded with front end code.

In my website design, I have the main `<?php ?>` section on top of the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` section. 
Then I echo certain parts from the main `<?php ?>` section at the top, within the front end code.

I am missing something here because I can't get this to work. I've tried various attempts.

This is the output in a stand alone php file

01-05-2015 sample 3

01-05-2015 sample 2

01-05-2015 sample

I want this in the search result  box using  isset if it doesn't exist yet.

Here is a photo of the interface if it helps, it is literally a text input field and a "search" post button with a result display below.

http://www.parsemebro.com/search.jpg

```
ob_start();
session_start();

 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
error_reporting(-1);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;

}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $errors = array();

if (empty($_POST['keyphrase'])) {
     $errors['keyphrase'] = "Search field is empty";
   } else {
     $keyphrase = test_input($_POST['keyphrase']);
   }

if(empty($errors)){

$userrname = $_SESSION["user"];
$keyphrase = test_input($_POST['keyphrase']);

$servername = " ";
$username = " ";
$password = " ";
$dbname = " ";

$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$stmt=$link->prepare('SELECT stratoparse,date FROM stock WHERE user=? AND keyphrase=? ORDER BY ID DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$userrname,$keyphrase);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
global $num_rows;
$stratoparse=null;
$date=null;
$stmt->bind_result($stratoparse,$date);

$rows2 = array();
$rows3 = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
$rows2[] = $stratoparse;
$rows3[] = $date;
}

$search = array();
for($i=0;$i<=$num_rows;$i++){
$search[]=$rows3[$i].'&nbsp;'.$rows2[$i].'<br>'.'<br>';
}

$_SESSION['status_message'] = "search results displayed below";

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // the path/file?query string of the page
        header("Location: http://$host$uri");
        exit;
        $link->close();
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['status_message'])){
    echo '<font color="white" size="30%">'.htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['status_message']).'</font>'.'&nbsp;';
    unset($_SESSION['status_message']); // clear the message
    }
?>
<span><span class="errors"><?php echo isset($errors['keyphrase'])? $errors['keyphrase']:""; ?></span>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type="text" name="keyphrase" value="<?php echo isset($keyphrase)? $keyphrase:"";?>" placeholder="keyphrase"><input type="submit" value="search"></span>
</form>
<textarea name="result" placeholder="search results">

**THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO OUTPUT THE ARRAY RESULTS** 

<?php echo isset($search)?$search:"";?>
<?php 

for($i=0;$i<=(isset ($num_rows)?$num_rows:"");$i++){
echo isset($search[$i])?$search[$i]:"".'<br>'.'<br>';
}

for($i=0;$i<=(isset ($num_rows)?$num_rows:"");$i++){
echo (isset($rows3[$i])?$rows3[$i]:"").'&nbsp;'.(isset($rows2[$i])?$rows2[$i]:"").'<br>'.'<br>';
}

?>
</textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: I wonder if I can accomplish this by setting the working array output as a function in a stand alone php file. Then I call the file and call the function... but then again is that any different from what I'm trying to do now?

Answer (score 0):

to output type Array, such as your $search[] you need to use var_dump($search). Then you should see some output. but it'll be ugly unless you iterate over it and concatenate a string.

To iterate over the array and concatenate into string using `".="`

```
$output = "";
for( $i = 0; $i < count($search); $i++){
    $output .= "Search result: " . $i . "\n";
    $output .= $search[$i] . "\n";
};
```

and then dont echo, just use `<?=$string?>` inside your HTML element.

```
<textarea name="result" placeholder="search results">
    <?=$output?>
</textarea>
```

Test if $search is set before beginning to loop over it to get the values out.

side-note:
In your HTML you can use `<?=$variableName?>` as syntax rather than `<?php ... ?>`.

Comment: I'm probably just not trying hard enough / exhausted but I'm not getting this to work, maybe there is something wrong like the session name isn't storing... I don't know...

Comment: Yeah it seems that the keyphrase isn't registering, I have tried to output it using $_POST and $keyphrase

Comment: I'm not sure, but the placeholder on the <taxtarea name=result> is maybe causing something strange to happen. Also the HTML "br"-taggs put into a textarea is not neccessary either. probably use escape-n (\n) for that.

Comment: I don't understand why this is so hard. I can get single strings to come out like error messages and what not which where generated in the above section. Why not an array? I'm going to try this again, I'll post my solution when I find one. I imagine yours is the way to go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if this is a foolish method. If upon post, the two bound parameter inputs where stored as session values, then the entire select statement / output was done at the html section. Not sure.